# PHP: strange string encoding in $_GET

Tags: php, encoding

I have the following string sent to the server by a client:

```
3%D3%E1f%7C%AF%B0a%B58%81%92%F9M%90%0CD%A0Y%9C // string in the actual URL
3Óáf|¯°aµ8’ùMD Yœ // var_dump($_GET)
```

The original string should be:

```
33D3E1667CAFB061B5388192F94D900C44A0599C
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to encode/decode this so I can peform a database search because the collation type does not match. I have tried to `urlencode`/`urldecode`, `mb_string_convert`, `utf8_encode`, `iconv`, but without luck. Any ideas ?

Laravel throws the following exception when trying to use the string for searching:

```
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)...
```

I have no control of what the client's encoding is. The strange value is from logging it to a log file using `Laravel's Log::imfo()`

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan: this is not an attack, it is me testing. he thing is I need that data in the original value.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: the client is a bittorrent client and the sent parameter is an info_hash one. The request is sent and received via GET, and I don't think that it can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to retrieve the parameter with the `bin2hex()` function call.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried sending a post request instead of a get request, and send the string as the actual string.

Or maybe change your database encoding to UTF-8 (it handles swedish just fine, no need to choose latin-swedish version).

Comment: Changing the database collation fixes part of the problem, namely the exception. The initial problem is solved by calling bin2hex(), as specified in my answer.